# Cómo utilizar librerías OpenSSL en Code:Blocks usando C?

Tags: c, codeblocks, openssl

Estoy tratando de utilizar algunas funciones básicas de OpenSSL como aprendizaje, por ejemplo, quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

int RAND_bytes(unsigned char *buf, int num);

unsigned char aux[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    RAND_bytes(aux,16);
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        printf("%02X ",aux[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

sin embargo lo único que obtengo es

```
In function `main': undefined reference to `RAND_bytes'
```

En Settings, Compiler, Search directories añadí la carpeta include donde tengo copiado OpenSSL; por otro lado, el instalador de MingW indica que el paquete de librería OpenSSL fue descargado, pero aún así no encuentra la referencia a RAND_bytes...

La verdad no tengo experiencia con esta librería, así que estoy bastante perdido... ¿Qué me está faltando considerar o incluir?

El archivo que bajé de OpenSSL es el openssl-master.zip, desde el sitio openssl.org

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda!!!

Comment: Al parecer el linker no encuentra la función que quieres usar. Asegúrate de que la enlazaste bien.

Answer (score -1):

Elimina el prototipo de función.

```
int RAND_bytes(unsigned char *buf, int num);
```